# Reporting values from multiple records in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I displaying multiple records in one row in oracle without creating a stored procedure?

Data Set:

```
Name        Job    Update_date
Armstrong   IDE    07/02/2014
Armstrong   IDE    05/02/2015
Armstrong   IDEC   03/02/2016
Armstrong   LT     14/02/2016
Beyonce     LT     12/02/2015
Beyonce     LTC    12/02/2016
Deadpool    LT     05/02/2015
```

Desired Result:

```
Name        IDE         IDEC        LT          LTC
Armstrong   05/02/2015  03/02/2016  14/02/2016  null
Beyonce     null        null        12/02/2015  12/02/2016
Deadpool    null        null        05/02/2015  null
```

For each job I must have the biggest dates

The solution I see is to create a temporary table by Job and make union with name!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Data_Set ( Name, Job, Update_date ) AS
SELECT 'Armstrong',   'IDE',    DATE '2014-02-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Armstrong',   'IDE',    DATE '2015-02-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Armstrong',   'IDEC',   DATE '2016-02-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Armstrong',   'LT',     DATE '2016-02-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beyonce',     'LT',     DATE '2015-02-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Beyonce',     'LTC',    DATE '2016-02-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Deadpool',    'LT',     DATE '2015-02-05' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT Name,
       MAX( CASE JOB WHEN 'IDE'  THEN Update_Date END ) AS IDE,
       MAX( CASE JOB WHEN 'IDEC' THEN Update_Date END ) AS IDEC,
       MAX( CASE JOB WHEN 'LT'   THEN Update_Date END ) AS LT,
       MAX( CASE JOB WHEN 'LTC'  THEN Update_Date END ) AS LTC
FROM   Data_Set
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```

**Results**:

```
NAME      IDE       IDEC      LT        LTC     
--------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
Armstrong 05-FEB-15 03-FEB-16 14-FEB-16           
Beyonce                       12-FEB-15 12-FEB-16 
Deadpool                      05-FEB-15
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do provided you know exactly which values can be found in `Job`. And in [11G](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) or newer, yes.

```
SELECT Name,
       IDE,
       IDEC,
       LT,
       LTC
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
PIVOT (
  MAX(Update_date)
  FOR Job IN ('IDE'  AS IDE,
              'IDEC' AS IDEC,
              'LT'   AS LT,
              'LTC'  AS LTC))
```